# Compare two different Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have to compare values of list of items in two different Excel tables. Items in both tables are essentially the same. It's just items in one table is old version and in another is new version. For instance, **ballistic helmet** and **helmet,ballistic** are the same thing. As names doesn't match I can't use MATCH function. There is another file where old and new names are listed side by side to search.
I can't think of logic and what formula to use so that I don't have to search individually each item name and compare their values. Community please help

Comment: Conditional Formatting?

Answer (score 2):

Alright so I attempted something. The question is kinda vague so I had to make a lot of assumptions but here we go:

I assumed that somewhere in your workbook, there is a table called "names" with a column of old and new names side by side, looking like this:

[image: names]

Then there is a table called "oldTable", looking like this:

[image: newTable]

And lastly a table called "newTable", looking like this:

[image]

And this is the formula I used to pull the "price" from the "oldTable" into the "newTable":

```
=INDEX(oldTable[price],MATCH(INDEX(names[oldNames],MATCH([@name],names[newNames],0),1),oldTable[name],0),1)
```

It's just 2 nested index, match pairs. The inner finds the corresponding old name in the "names" table, the outer one uses that to find the price in the "oldTable". You'll have to modify this to suit your needs.